# How do I calculate ratios in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a `GAME` table with the following fields

```
user_id, result
```

I wish to calculate win percentage defined as total number of records where

```
result = 'Win'
```

Compared to total number of records where

```
result <> ''
```

How can I do this in SQL and have the result returned in order with highest win percentage first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most database systems should be able to handle this with something akin to:

```
Select user_id
    , Sum( Case When Result = 'Win' Then 1 Else 0 End ) / Count(*) * 1.0 As WinPercent
From Game
Group By user_id
Order By WinPercent Desc
```

Btw, I'm assuming you meant to say the win percentage is the total number of wins out of the total number of games. If you really did mean `where result <> ''`, then you would need to modify the query like so:

```
Select user_id
    , Sum( Case When Result = 'Win' Then 1 Else 0 End ) 
        / Sum( Case When Result <> '' Then 1 Else 0 End ) * 1.0 As WinPercent
From Game
Group By user_id
Order By WinPercent Desc
```

**Addition**

It was suggested in comments that this is SQL Server specific. It is not. Everything in the above solutions is part of the SQL standard. Whether a given database system implements all of the features required is obviously another matter. So, if we are switching gears to finding a solution that would actually work on most database systems, the one feature that has the most variance in support would likely be the use of the column alias in the Order By. You can achieve the equivalent in a couple of ways but one way that would work on most database systems would be to use a derived table:

```
Select Z.user_id, Z.WinPercent
From    (
        Select user_id
            , Sum( Case When Result = 'Win' Then 1 Else 0 End ) 
                / Sum( Case When Result <> '' Then 1 Else 0 End ) * 1.0 As WinPercent
        From Game
        Group By user_id
        ) As Z
Order By Z.WinPercent Desc
```

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger - How do you figure this is SQL Server specific?

Comment: I thought `Case When` is not standard SQL. But you are right, it is ansi sql. I only knew it from sql server, oracle used to have this decode function.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can use this shortcut:

```
SELECT user_id, avg(Result = 'Win') AS WinPercent
FROM Game
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY WinPercent DESC
```

Assuming Result is never NULL (empty string is ok). Otherwise you have to use 
Result IS NOT NULL AND Result = 'Win'