# How to calculate the ratio of data from two tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table emp which has count of employees(company wise) and another table which has count of employees whose age is greater than 18 company wise. Now i want to display the percentage of employees who are greater than 18 company wise

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate ratios in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114401/how-do-i-calculate-ratios-in-sql)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP18) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP)
```

Comment: You should do: `* 100.0`

Comment: Cool, giving a whole lot of numbers after the point. I'll edit (see above).

Comment: where is "group by company"
Ex: If i  have two companies facebook and google and there are certain no. of employees in each company then i want to calculate the ratio for facebook and google seperately