# How to calcule a ratio row by row in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I have the following table :

```
Spect    isin    ticker
bonds     55       26
equity    36       89
```

And another one :

```
Spect    totalnb
bonds       200
equity      200
```

I would like to calculate the ratio of Isin and ticker among the totalnb of spec like in SQL server:

```
Spect    ratio_isin    ratio_ticker
bonds     27       13
equity    18       39
```

I have already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114401/how-do-i-calculate-ratios-in-sql) but it works well only on 2 columns

Comment: Please explain the logic you are using.  It looks like you are just dividing by 2.

Comment: what is data type of your (isin and  ticker) column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple join as follows

```
/*
create table SpectDetail(Spect varchar(10), isin int, ticker int)
create table SpectTotal(Spect varchar(10), totalnb int)
insert into SpectDetail select 'bonds',55,26
insert into SpectDetail select 'equity',36,89
insert into SpectTotal select 'bonds',200
insert into SpectTotal select 'equity',200
*/
select
    t.Spect, 
    d.isin * 100 / t.totalnb ratio_isin, 
    d.ticker * 100/ t.totalnb ratio_ticker
from SpectTotal t 
inner join SpectDetail d on d.Spect = t.Spect
```

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
select t1.spect
, t1.isin / t2.totalnb * 100 as ratio_isin
, t1.ticker / t2.totalnb * 100 as ratio_ticker
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Spect = t1.spect
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your ISIN and Ticker column is INT:**

```
SELECT
    T1.Spect,
    CAST((CAST (T1.ISIN AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(T2.TotalNB AS DECIMAL(10,2)) )*100 AS INT) AS Ratio_ISIN,
    CAST((CAST (T1.Ticker AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(T2.TotalNB AS DECIMAL(10,2)) )*100 AS INT) AS Ratio_Ticker
FROM @tblTest1 T1 
LEFT JOIN @tblTest2 T2 ON T1.Spect=T2.Spect
```

**If your ISIN and Ticker column is Decimal:**

```
SELECT
    T1.Spect,
    CAST((T1.ISIN / T2.TotalNB )*100 AS INT) AS Ratio_ISIN,
    CAST((T1.Ticker / T2.TotalNB )*100 AS INT) AS Ratio_Ticker
FROM @tblTest1 T1 
LEFT JOIN @tblTest2 T2 ON T1.Spect=T2.Spect
```